# SetWindowPlacement sometimes fails for maximized windows

Tags: delphi

We store and reload window positions using the `GetWindowPlacement`/`SetWindowPlacement` API routines. This up to now worked well.

Now sometimes this fails to properly reload a maximized window: The window doesn't cover the whole work area like it should. But the window "believes" it is maximized:

- It shows a "Restore" button instead of "Maximize".
  [image: screenshot of window title bar]
- Its `WindowState` is `wsMaximized`.
- Calling `GetWindowPlacement` yields `showCmd = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`.

I tried a few workarounds like calling `ShowWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)` directly or delayed with `PostMessage` and assigning `WindowState` but to no avail. Unfortunately I'm unable to extract a SSCCE for the issue. Maybe you have advice how to fix the issue from the mentioned symptoms without one?

Comment: Attempting to resize a maximized window, without restoring it, can cause this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480394/wsmaximized-forms-do-not-appear-maximized) for an example.